# How to use MAX in nested LINQ expression

Tags: linq

> I am **VERY** new to LINQ expressions and I'm learning but I'm curious about this one roadblock that I've hit. Everything else seems straightforward but this was surprisingly confusing for me. (Maybe because I'm new to lambda expressions too)

### Problem

- I am trying to translate a nested SQL query into LINQ expression for my webapp
- So far, I can confim that the nested query works but I cannot seem to apply MAX to the selection

### Snippet

```
SELECT * FROM Promotion AS p
    INNER JOIN Student AS s ON p.stdId = s.StdID
    INNER JOIN CLASS AS c ON p.class_Id = c.CLASS_ID
    INNER JOIN BatchMgr AS b ON p.batchId = b.batchId
WHERE p.promotionId
IN( SELECT MAX(promotionId)
    FROM Promotion
    GROUP BY stdId
    );
```

I'm trying to translate that into LINQ and this is where I'm at

```
var subquery = (   from promotion in db.promotion.DefaultIfEmpty()
                   group promotion by new
                   {
                       promotionId = promotion.promotionId
                   }
                   into gpromotion
                   select gpromotion.Key.promotionId
                        );

var res = ( from p in db.promotion.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join s in db.students on p.stdId
            equals s.StdID into students
            join c in db.classes on p.class_Id
            equals c.CLASS_ID into classes
            join b in db.batchmgr on p.batchId
            equals b.BatchId into batchmgr
            from b in batchmgr.DefaultIfEmpty()
            from c in classes.DefaultIfEmpty()
            from s in students.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where subquery.Contains(p.promotionId)
            select new { s.NAME, s.StdID, p.class_Id, c.CLASSNO, p.promotionId, p.promotedYear, b.BatchId, b.BatchOf, s.ENROLLEDYEAR }
            ).AsEnumerable();
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, res.ToArray());
```

As you can see from `select gpromotion.Key.promotionId` , I haven't been able to figure out how to select the maximum `promotionId`. All the examples and answers that I've found so far seems to only query and return the highest `promotionId`. I do not want that. I require the highest `promotionId` for the same `stdId`.

### I've tried

- using `select gpromotion.Key.promotionId.Max(x => x.promoitonId)` *but that failed.*
- various SO answers *but they could only filter out one answer*

> ### Fiddle
>
> [This](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/602a2/70) is what my code is supposed to do(in SQL)
>
> As you can see, my requirement is to remove entries like [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/602a2/25) and show [only the latest promotionId](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/602a2/70).

---

I'm sure I'll be kicking myself when I find out the solution but for now, this is really troublesome. Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the LINQ equivalent of the SQL subquery in question.

*Method syntax:*

```
var subquery = db.promotion
    .GroupBy(p => p.stdId)
    .Select(g => g.Max(p => p.promotionId));
```

*Query syntax:*

```
var subquery =
    from p in db.promotion
    group p by p.stdId into g
    select g.Max(p => p.promotionId);
```

It's pretty standard LINQ `group by` query with aggregates. All you need is to learn how to use [`IGrouping<TKey, TElement>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.igrouping-2?view=netframework-4.6.1) produced by the `GroupBy` operator.

Comment: +1 The `Query Syntax` is really very clean! Its exactly what I wanted. It seems I was confused at `group promotion by new { promotionId = promotion.promotionId} into gpromotion` earlier in my snippet. I found a similar example in an unrelated SO question a while ago. I had thought it was a grouping procedure. Could you kindly tell me what `{...}` does in this instance? Is it used to perform multiple groupbys? #confused Thanks! :)

Comment: Also, what is the __REAL__ difference in using Method syntax and Query syntax. Is it just dependent on developer preference or does one has concrete advantage over the other in some cases? I really like the query syntax btw. Ok thanks in advance again.

Comment: (2) The 2 syntaxes do exactly one and the same. Which one you use is a matter of personal preference. I've provided both because from your post it looks like you prefer the "query" syntax. (1) The `new { ... }` is usually used when you need more than one property. You can also use it for one property (e.g. `new { p.stdId }`). The only difference would be the type of the `Key` (in case you need it), e.g. `g.Key` vs `g.Key.stdId`.

Comment: Also as you can see, the syntaxes can be mixed. I usually select the more compact version, for instance `g.Max(p => p.promotionId)` can be written in query syntax as well - `(from p in g select p.promotionId).Max()` which I find less readable. The real benefit of query syntax is with multiple joins like your main query - the equivalent method syntax would be ugly and unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
var res = ( from p in db.promotion
            join s in db.students on p.stdId equals s.StdID 
            join c in db.classes on p.class_Id equals c.CLASS_ID 
            join b in db.batchmgr on p.batchId equals b.BatchId
            let maxPromotionId = (db.promotion.Where(x => x.stdId == s.StdID).Max(m => m.promotionId))
            where maxPromotionId == p.promotionId            
            select new { s.NAME, s.StdID, p.class_Id, c.CLASSNO, p.promotionId, p.promotedYear, b.BatchId, b.BatchOf, s.ENROLLEDYEAR }
            ).AsEnumerable();
```

Comment: +1 I didn't know about `let`; I wouldn't have considered; how convenient! Again, this is really clean code but doesn't it lose in readability without a subquery in very big queries? Or does it have some hidden advantage over subqueries that I am unaware of!? Regardless, this is great. ps. I noticed you left out `into` in inner join. Is it because the columns are distinguished already? Thanks! :) Great effort!